# How to access from a Windows CE 3.0 system to a shared folder in a Windows 10 server?

Tags: windows-10, shared-folders

I have a Siemens MP370 panel, that uses Windows CE 3.0 operative system and I want to access from it the shared folder in a Windows 10 server.

I am following this guide: https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/document/13336639/how-do-you-incorporate-an-operator-panel-created-with-wincc-flexible-2008-into-a-local-network-in-order-to-save-archive-data-on-the-pc-?dti=0&lc=en-ES

in Summary, the main point it is to enable SMB 1.0 in the server, because it is the version that is used in Windows CE. In the server I have also a user that have permissions to modify at level of network and in the security options of the folder.

From the panel, in the file explorer, I can find the shared folder and I am prompted all the time for the credentials, so I can't access to the folder.

In the server, if in the events viewer, in the SMB server events, I get this error:

SMB Session Authentication Failure

```
Client Name: \\192.168.1.201
Client Address: 192.168.1.201:1026
User Name: eeee
Session ID: 0x0
Status: The attempted logon is invalid. This is either due to a bad username or authentication information. (0xC000006D)
SPN: session setup failed before the SPN could be queried
SPN Validation Policy: SPN optional / no validation

Guidance:

You should expect this error when attempting to connect to shares using incorrect credentials.

This error does not always indicate a problem with authorization, but mainly authentication. It is more common with non-Windows clients.

This error can occur when using incorrect usernames and passwords with NTLM, mismatched LmCompatibility settings between client and server, an incorrect service principal name, duplicate Kerberos service principal names, incorrect Kerberos ticket-granting service tickets, or Guest accounts without Guest access enabled
```

So it seems there is a problem authentication the client.`

It says that the credentials are incorrect, but it is not true.

Thanks.

Comment: You may have to look into enabling SMBv1 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/troubleshoot/smbv1-not-installed-by-default-in-windows) which is no longer installed by default in Windows due to security risks. Seems to be more information at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/2cc69c0f-7030-41f3-8463-d5ed8391b8a9/windows-ce-30-can8217t-connect-to-shared-folder-on-windows-server-2008-r2?forum=winservergen

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I know that, it is the first I did, to ebale SMB v1.0

Comment: Windows CE 3.0 is a bit outdated (it should be more than 20 years old). So may be it tries to use NTLMv1 authentication which is disabled for security reasons?

Comment: @Robert thanks for the suggetsion. How could I enable NTLMv1? in the same way I enabled SMB v1.0?  Thanks so much.

Comment: Talk to your admins who manage the group policy of your domain? Anyway I strongly recommend to not lower your security just because of a 20 year old hardware that can be replaced for a few hundred dollar. The next ransom ware attack will cost you much more.

Comment: @Robert Yes, the best it would have the system updated, but in this case an industrial panel that runs with Windows CE 3.0 and I can't update it. So I have to try to find to solve the problem. Anyway it will be an isolated system, without internet connection, just a connection between the panel and the PC.